# Is there an alternative way to add another Registered Cloud to Visual Studio?

Tags: azure, visual-studio, visual-studio-2019

I've lost the ability to log in to Visual Studio using my work account which is prohibiting me from being able to connect to my Azure Dev Ops repos. I believe the reason is because it's trying to auth me against Azure Gov instead of Azure Comm where my account lives.

When I go to my account options I see the US Azure Gov cloud as registered and when I click "Add" I can see the other Gov clouds; but I don't see the commercial cloud. And when I try to add `https://login.microsoftonline.com/` manually, it complains that the server returned a 404. Doing a trace reveals the GET to the metadata endpoint is the culprit. `https://login.microsoftonline.com/metadata/endpoints?api-version=1.0`

I've checked with other developers and they do have it in their list along with the others I have; they have no issues logging in or connecting to the repos. We're running the same major version of VS 2019 - 16.8.x.

Is there an alternative way to register the comm cloud or get that list to be populated with it?

---

UPDATE: updated to 16.9.4 without luck.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My google-fu finally kicked in and I found a [solution](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/answers/questions/77002/cannot-log-into-visual-studio-2019.html).

Near the bottom of the answer from TianyuSun-MSFT, they suggest:

> ...you can also close all Visual Studio instances and go to C:\Users[user name]\AppData\Local.IdentityService then rename(or delete) the .IdentityService folder, after that you can restart Visual Studio 2019 and try to log in again.

That worked. But before I did it, I investigated the json configs in there and saw a lot pertaining to older versions I no longer have installed. Perhaps, that was the issue.

Once I restarted and logged in, the commercial cloud was automatically added to the list of Registered Clouds.